# want to parametrize the value in ansible playbook with jenkins parameters

Tags: jenkins, automation, ansible, devops

I am trying to delete server log files which are more than a month old. I can use this set of Ansible tasks:

```yaml
- name: Remove JBOSS Log Files 
  find: 
    path: /u01/jboss/server 
    patterns: "server.log.*" 
    age: "30d" 
  register: deleted
  tags: serverlog

- name: Ansible remove File 
  file: 
    path: "{{ item.path }}" 
    state: absent 
  with_items: "{{ deleted.files }}"
  tags: serverlog
```

Since I want to allow this age to be controlled, the `days` variable  below has to be entered as user input from the jenkins parameter section. It is a string parameter and I have given it a default value of `20d` so that 20 days of log files can be retained and the rest can be removed.

```yaml
- name: Remove JBOSS Log Files 
  find: 
    path: /u01/jboss/server 
    patterns: "server.log.*" 
    age: "{{ days }}" 
  register: deleted
  tags: serverlog

- name: Ansible remove File 
  file: 
    path: "{{ item.path }}" 
    state: absent 
  with_items: "{{ deleted.files }}"
  tags: serverlog
```

In the execution command of jenkins I have passed the command

`ansible-playbook main.yml --tags serverlog`

This is removing the complete log from server.
How can it be parameterised for user convenience to keep the log files of 20 days and delete the older log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass days parameter in your pipeline and run the playbook by giving command
`ansible-playbook --extra-vars '{"days":"${params.days}"}' main.yml`

I am sharing a sample pipeline job which will use jenkins parameter in ansible playbook.

**Pipeline job:**

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages {
    stage ('Git Pull') {
        steps {
            git changelog: false, poll: false, url: '/var/lib/jenkins/ansible-workspace'
        }
    }
    stage ('Run PLaybook') {
        steps {
            
            sh """ansible-playbook --extra-vars '{"name":"${params.first_name}"}' deploy.yml"""
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Ansible playbook:** (deploy.yml)

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    - firstname: "John"
  roles:
    - { role: helloworld }
```

I have added the sample ansible playbook roles in [github](https://github.com/souravatta/test-ansible)

**Jenkins pipeline configuration**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I suggest you move your suggestion to the top of your answer, so that @vodevops can see the point before reading the explanation

Comment: should this be like```
- name: Remove JBOSS Log Files 
  find: 
    path: /u01/jboss/server 
    patterns: "server.log.*" 
    age: "{{ days }}" 
  register: deleted
  tags: serverlog

- name: Ansible remove File 
  file: 
    path: "{{ item.path }}" 
    state: absent 
  with_items: "{{ deleted.files }}"
  tags: serverlog

Comment: the above playbook is tasks in roles, where do we enter the vars ?
`ansible-playbook --extra-vars '{"days":"${params.days}"}' main.yml`
Can this be passed in exec command of jenkins configuration with out passing days in pipeline?

Comment: @vodevops I have added the ansible playbook as roles in [github](https://github.com/souravatta/test-ansible) You can add **days** parameter in vars folder of your ansible role. Here, I have **helloworld** as ansible role.